# What is the right way to write a bash script for cron job

Tags: bash, cron, relative-path

I have written a bash script that is supposed to be executed by a cron job. But according to the cron output one of the lines in the bash script is not executing.

Here is my bash script

```
#! /bin/bash
/usr/bin/mysql</home/elijah/Desktop/covid-19-management-tool/cron_job/import.sql
./home/elijah/Desktop/covid-19-management-tool/cron_job/clear
```

This is the output I got from cron after execution

```
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <20210205172001.F3C5FE221D@elijah-HP-255-G6-Notebook-PC>
Date: Fri,  5 Feb 2021 20:20:01 +0300 (EAT)

/home/elijah/Desktop/covid-19-management-tool/cron_job/dbs.sh: line 3: ./home/elijah/Desktop/covid-19-management-tool/cron_job/clear: No such file or directory

--F3C5FE221D.1612545602/elijah-HP-255-G6-Notebook-PC--
```

For line 3 in my bash script I want to run an executable called `clear`.

Someone please tell me how I should do it in the shell script so that cron can understand it.

Comment: 2 things to be wary of for cron jobs: differences between your environment and cron's environment; relative paths. And the `%` character in the cron entry. (And, apparently, off-by-one errors)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `.` before `/home` (unless you have indeed the following directory structure):

```
/home/elijah/home/elijah/Desktop/covid-19-management-tool/cron_job/clear
```

The `.` makes this a relative path, while it's most likely meant to be absolute.